# Using fromCodePoint or other alternative on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am leveraging on this emoji picker javascript from https://www.cssscript.com/simple-emoji-picker-text-fields-emoji-picker/

In the script, String.codePointAt is having issue working on IE.

I know IE do not support codePointAt, is there any other alternative or workaround to get it on IE?

```
     const emojis = [0x1f600]

emojis.map(function (item) {
        const emojiLi = document.createElement("li");
        emojiLi.style.display = "inline-block";
        emojiLi.style.paddingTop = "10px";

        const emojiLink = document.createElement("a");

        emojiLink.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");
        emojiLink.innerHTML = String.fromCodePoint(item);
        emojiLink.onmousedown = clickLink;

        emojiList.appendChild(emojiLink);
    });
```

I tried using

```
String.fromCharCode(item);
```

However it somehow corrupt the unicode translation:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG6mN.png)

Comment: you can add a polyfill library, e.g. https://polyfill.io/v3/, I think is the easiest solution.

Comment: According to Davabra you can refer to this link for polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Polyfill